# Reusable Collection View cells showing weird behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to do the following thing:

```
var timer = Timer()
timer.invalidate()

extension InviteViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return totalItems 
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "IT1Cell", for: indexPath) as! InviteTasker1CellView
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.taskerName.text = names[indexPath.item]

        return cell


    }

    @objc func deleteCellUtil()
    {
        totalItems -= 1
        names.remove(at: selectedIndexPath.item)
        collectionView1.deleteItems(at: [selectedIndexPath])
        timer.invalidate()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if(!timer.isValid)
        {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? InviteTasker1CellView
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
            cell?.invitedView.isHidden = false
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(deleteCellUtil), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        }

    }

}
```

When user clicks on a cell, it gets deleted. Before deletion, I am setting up  **cell?.invitedView.isHidden = false** to show the user that his request was processed. However because of reusability of cells, this reflects in cells in the collection view. How do I avoid this fallback? I am unable to understand what to do in this situation. Please help me with the same.

Comment: Do `cell?.invitedView.isHidden = true` in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`? Why do you use `totalItems`? What about using `names.count` instead? That should avoid use another var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the `invitedView.isHidden` state to `false` in `didSelectItemAt` but you are not changing it back to true anywhere.

You have to add:

```
cell?.invitedView.isHidden = true
```

in `cellForItemAt` so that when cell is reused it will change the state.

Irrelevant from the question. But it's better you write `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` separate just to keep the code a bit clean like this :

```
extension InviteViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource {
}

extension InviteViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and advice.